# dplyr group_by and replace all columns with a function of the group

Tags: r, dplyr

Minimal example - a data frame with responses to 3 questions and a Delay, with the respondent's sex. I'd like to replace the responses to each of the questions with the average response for the respondent's sex.

```
df <- data.frame(Sex = c(rep("F", 5), rep("M", 5)),
                 Q1  = sample(0:10, 10, replace=T),
                 Q2  = sample(0:10, 10, replace=T),
                 Q3  = sample(0:10, 10, replace=T),
                 Delay = 1:10 
)
QUESTIONS <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")
```

I then try to replace all the reponses by the average response by sex and wrote

```
df %>%
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  mutate(all_of(QUESTIONS), mean)
  ungroup()
```

but get an error message that I can't decipher

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 5.
i Input `..1` is `all_of(QUESTIONS)`.
i Input `..1` must be size 5 or 1, not 3.
i The error occurred in group 1: Sex = "F".
```

What is the error in  my mutate statement, and how might I resolve it. I have tried variants of `all_of` such as `across(all_of(QUESTIONS))` and replacing `mean` with `colMeans` without success. It seems to me that I am making an elementary error with syntax, but am stuck, and would appreciate some guidance.

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 1):

My mistake - just misplaced the parentheses. Should have written `df %>% group_by(Sex) %>% mutate(across(QUESTIONS, mean)) %>% ungroup()`. Apologies.